# prototype conflicts with other jquery plugins in magento

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, magento-1.7, prototypejs, prototype

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 which has prototype version 1.7 and i am using some plugins to achieve the requirement.

I placed all the plugins in page.xml under prototype.js.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>

<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</script></action> 
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.noconflict.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery_slider.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/slider.js</script></action>   
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/global.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js</script></action>
```

I placed `plugin.js` in header.phtml.

Now i am getting lot of issues. `Add to cart button` not working, `checkout not loading`. when i run my site it shows lot of errors like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:6483
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:6491

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:6483
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:6599
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderMenu' of null
```

I tried to solve the issue. Like i put all the necessary `plugins before prototype.js` and after that i placed `noConflict.js` file. `It worked`. `No errors were showing.` `Add to cart button started working`, `checkout started loading`.

But then the issue appears. `Like most of the plugins stopped working.` I tried a lot but cant dealt with the issue. So if you guys can help.

Comment: put prototype script tag in after jQuery no conflict so jQuery will have already removed itself from `$` alias

Comment: In that case all plugins stopped working..i tried that

Comment: what's in the file `noconflict.js`?

Comment: It contains jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: can chat here...start a chat room

Comment: Are any of your plugins using the $() shortcut instead of jQuery() internally?